# Javascript onclick event to area

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add onclick event through javascript to my map element that was created through javascript too , I am not going to paste whole code here but will make a short version .
so this what I have done so far:

```
 var mapimg = createElement("img"); // create and set up img element for map 
mapimg.src "some path ";
map.img.width = some with;
map.img.height = some height;
map.usemap = "#Map"; // img element done
var map = createElement("map"); // set map element and attributes for him 
map.name = "Map";
map.id = "Map";
area(1-10) = createElement("area"); // creating a 10 areas 
area.id = some;
area.shape = some;
area.coords = some; // area allement have same attributes but with different values 
// ones i done with are append them to map and then append mapimg and map to body 

//  now trying to add on click event 

map.addEventListener("onClick",function(){
            var id = map.getElementById(this);
            var img = "images/map/reg" + id + ".jpg";
            mapimg.src = img;
        });
```

map are working but onclick event are not working i have writed jquery version that works just fine with a html elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('area').click(function() {
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                var image = "images/map/reg" + title + ".jpg";
                $('.mapimg').attr('src', image);
                $('#loginsubmitbutton2').show();
                $('input[name="village"]').attr('value', title);
            })

        });
```

[this is a full script](https://jsfiddle.net/n0p8kjyf/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple elements with an event listener for each one of them is inefficient. jQuery makes it easy by using `$(document)` as `event.target` (i.e. the element clicked, hovered, etc.). In plain JavaScript it's possible as well by adding the event listener on the ancestor of the multiple elements.

1. `addEventListener()` to an element that contains the group of elements.
2. `event.preventDefault()` if `event.target`s (i.e. the group of elements you want to click) default behavior is undesired (e.g. if `e.target` is an `<a>`nchor and you don't want it to jump to somewhere like it normally does).
3. Set a conditional that will verify what is in the `eventPhase`* is an `event.target` and not the `event.currentTarget`*.
4. After that important step, you do all of your intended tasks of your functions at this point.
5. After your functions have completed their tasks, use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling* so that no other events are triggered on anything else.

   * TD;LR for details on event methods and properties read: [eventPhase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase), [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), and [Comparison of Event Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets)

   Also, read this [article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) about this particular technique.

The following Snippet demonstrates how you use one event listener on a `<map>` and assign each `<area>` as a unique `event.target`. To test it, simply click a planet, and the result will be the coordinates of the `event.target` and msg that the click event was triggered. Click anywhere that's not covered by a planet, and you get no result, that's the `event.stopPropagation()` working.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var map = document.querySelector('map');

map.addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false);

function eventHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    var clicked = e.target.coords;
    console.log('click event triggered at ' + clicked);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/80/f3/06/80f3061369194bef1e2025d9a382d1a2.jpg" usemap='#iMap'>
<map id="iMap" name="iMap">
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="66,179,10" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="198,141,13" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="152,244,17" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="107,124,17" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="353,203,83" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="438,235,29" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="482,135,25" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="499,271,6" href="" target="" />
  <area shape="circle" alt="" title="" coords="262,243,99" href="" target="" />
  <!-- Created by Online Image Map Editor (http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/index) -->
</map>
```

Comment: there is a mistake in your code when attribute usemap of img element your code "usemap='iMap'" it should be "usemap'#iMap'"

Comment: Oops forgot the `#` hashmark, will update thanks, it still works though.

Comment: for some reason its works only for a half of window the bottom side , i am trying to investigate this now but coords seems to be good , i wondering could it be because of very long coordinates ?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? I'm using Chrome Win10. The way it works is the planets are clicked on and there should be a console message. If any white area is clicked, nothing should happen.

Comment: your code works fine but i am trying this now on my own code its works only for the half of screen , i am using a windows 7 and firefox , my code are at the top inside fiddle everything is same there only my coordinates are much much longer then in the sample u provide

Comment: only the blue color marked are respond to click http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b578/yahoo5000/regmap_zpsjdqzkrmj.jpg

Comment: I see what it might be, your `var map` is in another scope. It's declared inside another function. You can declare another `var map` with `querySelector` or `getElementByTagName()` or `getElementById()` outside of the `addEventListener()` then it should work.

Comment: @RahulArora thank you, sir. I think I fixed it. http://plnkr.co/edit/mLgDRhhLLjkHfuq5Cz6t?p=preview

Comment: @yahoo5000 The Naruto Map works now. Minor changes: separated the `setRegistration()` from `eventListener()` and `eventHandler()` / Called on `setRegistration()` before `addEventListener()` and changed `console.log("clicked")` to `console.log(clicked);` Now you can see the title of each land/villiage.

Comment: yea its works there i tried to append same at my full code but i got same https://jsfiddle.net/n0p8kjyf/3/ i called setRegistration in my main function and then use selector and eventhandler same as you did on this sample but for me its still only half screen , if u copy paste your code inside mine i got two maps one fully working and one are just half of it

Comment: Well if you can identify a possible area of the other code that's causing the problem, post it in another question and refer to this one. If you are using Word-Press, Joomla, etc. I would have no idea.

Comment: Oh ok, you have multiple maps. You can wrap each individual map in a div or figure if you care for semantics, then you addeventListener to each wrapper.

Comment: Or use `var maps = document.querySelectorAll('map');` Then you can refer to them as `map[0]` and `map[1]` and `addEventListener()` to each one.

Answer (score 4):

It should not be **onclick** it should be just **click** when using addEventListener

```
    map.addEventListener("click",function(){
        var id = map.getElementById(this);
        var img = "images/map/reg" + id + ".jpg";
        mapimg.src = img;
    });
```

OR if you want to use onclick

```
    map.onclick = function(){
        var id = map.getElementById(this);
        var img = "images/map/reg" + id + ".jpg";
        mapimg.src = img;
    };
```

> How to add event listener to repeating elements inside a parent
>   without looping through all of them

If you want to add event to multiple repeated elements inside a parent element, rather than looping through all the elements and wasting memory a good solution is to use the concept of **event propagation** as explained in the code below: (since I understand **map** is the parent of **area**)

```
map.addEventListener("click", myFunction());
//we attach an event listener to the parent

function myFunction(e){
    //e.currentTarget : to which event listener is attached
    //e.target: the element which was clicked
    if(e.target !== e.currentTarget){
       //we only need to hear events from the area (children of map), so we ignore any other events that are called when the parent is clicked by this if statement
        var id = e.target.Id;

        alert(id);
        //your code here

    }
    e.stopPropagation(); //we stop the propagation of event to the DOM once its purpose is solved 

}
```

This solution is independent of the number of area elements you have. You will avoid using any for loop and wasting memory.

Comment: but i still got no result ones i click on any of areas

Comment: Try adding the same event to 'area' instead of 'map'

Comment: yea but i have area1-10 so to do that i have to make a loop , i do not think that its the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Use click instead of onclick,you can simply use id instead of getElementById

```
map.addEventListener("click",function(){
            var id = this.id;
            var img = "images/map/reg" + id + ".jpg";
            mapimg.src = img;
        });
```